# Multi level type guards

Tags: typescript

Given the following code, how can I modify the `isAppErrorOfKind` type guard in order for the return type to be `AppErrorHttp` or `AppErrorNetwork` based on the `kind` specified?

```
type AppError = AppErrorHttp | AppErrorNetwork | AppErrorUnsupported;

interface AppErrorHttp {
  kind: 'http';
  status: number;
}

interface AppErrorNetwork {
  kind: 'network';
  reason: string;
}

interface AppErrorUnsupported {
  kind: 'unsupported';
  api: string;
}

function isAppError(error: Error | AppError): error is AppError {
  if (error === undefined || error === null) return false;
  if (typeof(error) !== 'object') return false;
  return 'kind' in error;
}

function isAppErrorOfKind(error: Error | AppError, kind: AppError['kind']): error is XXX {
  if (!isAppError(error)) return false;
  return error.kind === kind;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to infer `kind` argument:

```js
type AppError = AppErrorHttp | AppErrorNetwork | AppErrorUnsupported;

interface AppErrorHttp {
  kind: 'http';
  status: number;
}

interface AppErrorNetwork {
  kind: 'network';
  reason: string;
}

interface AppErrorUnsupported {
  kind: 'unsupported';
  api: string;
}


function isAppError(error: Error | AppError): error is AppError {
  if (error === undefined || error === null) return false;
  if (typeof error !== 'object') return false;
  return 'kind' in error;
}

function isAppErrorOfKind<Kind extends AppError['kind']>(
  error: Error | AppError,
  kind: Kind
): error is Extract<AppError, { kind: Kind }> {
  if (!isAppError(error)) return false;
  return error.kind === kind;
}

const foo = (arg: AppError) => {
  if (isAppErrorOfKind(arg, 'network')) {
    arg // AppErrorHttp
  } else {
    arg // AppErrorHttp | AppErrorUnsupported
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m35ykw)

Comment: This only works when you have two cases by pointing out the other one. I have updated the snippet to include three cases.

Comment: You solution works if instead of `Exclude` we use `Extract`. I will take it but please update :)

Comment: @NekronSN updated. I'm always confusing these two utility types

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question correctly, I would perhaps use a generic type constraint:

```
function isAppErrorOfKind<T extends AppError>(error: T, kind: AppError["kind"]): error is T {
  if (!isAppError(error)) return false;
  return error.kind === kind;
}
```

You can then only pass in an error of type AppError, extending AppErrorHttp and AppErrorNetwork.

Comment: This solution requires to specify the type on usage. Do you know of a way to infer it from the `kind`?